# Comparing query output from two different servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server 2014. I need to compare data from two queries on separate servers.

Can someone help please?

Many thanks

Comment: Heard about linked server ?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take different approach depending on many situations:

**If the two servers are visible each other and you can create a database link**

Create a database link and use it to compare the data

**If the two servers are not visible or you can't create a database link**

1) Extract the data sorted from both databases and compare them row by row with a simple text comparator. You need to extract the raw data in the same order of columns and with the same format for columns that need convertion to test.

2) Use an ETL tool (Pentaho for example) to import both tables in a third database and compare them directly

3) Manually import both tables in a third database and compare them directly

Comment: 4) Backup and restore

Comment: @Davide Lorenzo. Thank you. Can I use something like this to first connect :CONNECT ? I need a report at the end to tell me the differences. I cannot write an ETL program. Any syntax would be much appreciated. In the meantime I am working on some SAS code to see if this will be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I ran both queries separately.  Outputted to Excel and used vba code to compare.